# How do you create a has_many association with multiple types?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, polymorphic-associations

I have the following:

- a Link model
- a LinkItem model, which I want to be of the following type

  - a comment
  - a tag
  - ...

I am using this code:

**Link model**

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :link_items  
end
```

**LinkItem model**

```
class LinkItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :link
end

class Comment < LinkItem
end

class Tag < LinkItem
end
```

Now I don't know how to tell Rails that my LinkItem model is supposed to be polymorphic. I've read the Rails Guide on asociations and other tutorials, but these just describe how to create a belongs_to association to multiple other models, not the other way around.

So my question would be:
How do I create a has_many association where the associated instances can be of different types? Or would it be better to create seperate models for comments, tags, etc. and just associate each of them individually with my Link model?

**EDIT**
Actually my code works.
I just tried using a 'type'-column (instead of 'link_item_type') in my database and rails automatically used it to save/determine the correct subclass of my LinkItems (thanks Wizard of Ogz for the hint)
However I still can't access the subclasses of LinkItem without referencing a LinkItem first. Is this some kind of lazyloading?

Comment: That should work without making the association polymorphic.  Did you try it out?

Comment: I tried, but I get an 'uninitialized constant Tag' error whenever I try to access the Tag class (same for Comment). As soon as I create an instance of LinkItem, Tag and Comment become accessible.. Also i can't distinguish between the items as a requested LinkItem is always returned as an instance of LinkItem, not of Tag or Comment.

Comment: hrm...Tags and Comments should be instantiated as such.  When evaluated `link.link_items` should return an array comprised of any combination of `LinkItem`, `Comment` and `Tag` records.  Maybe the 'type' column for the records you are testing is set to NULL, in which case ActiveRecord will just instantiate all of them as `LinkItem.`

Comment: The correct typing for my subclasses works. As I request `link.link_items` I get the array exactly as you mentioned. My error was to use a `link_item_type` column instead of just `type`. The guide @nicholaides mentioned was a bit misleading in my case because there the former naming convention was used, i.e. `imageable_type` instead of `type` (see `CreatePictures < ActiveRecord::Migration` in the guide). However I still get `NameError: uninitialized constant Tag` whenever I try to access the `Tag` model without making a call to `LinkItem` first. This is only when in development mode.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for polymorphic  association [nicholaides](https://stackoverflow.com/users/48424/nicholaides)  has the right way .
If you are looking for has_meny  polymorphic  association , check out [the answer to "Setting up a polymorphic has_many :through relationship"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886738/setting-up-a-polymorphic-has-many-through-relationship).

Comment: Unfortunately this is just another example of belongs_to. A tag is assigned to *one* object (belongs_to) which can be an article or one of many other models which can have tags. I want one object which has_many objects that can be a tag, a comment, etc. But as I mentioned in my EDIT above my code works now. Maybe polymorphic association is a bit misleading or the wrong term in my case?

Answer (score 0):

This is called a polymorphic association. Here is some [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).

Comment: Yes, this is the guide i was talking about, but it only describes how to make the **belongs_to** association polymorphic, not the **has_many**.

Comment: Look at the first code example. The 2nd class uses "has_many ..., :as => ..."

Comment: But this example only uses one Picture model, not several subclasses of it, eg. Photo < Picture, Thumbnail < Picture, etc.. @wizard-of-ogz already mentioned the type column I needed to make my example work without any :as, :polymorphic, ... But thank you none the less!

Answer (score 0):

I just dealt with what I think is the same issue.

My filename for my model was wrong.  I initially created it with one name (ex. link_tag.rb), and then changed the name of the class (ex. from LinkTag to Tag) on the fly without changing the name of the file (ex. tag.rb).

When I renamed the file correctly, it worked as expected.

In summary, the name of the file needed to match the name of the class.

I know this post is a little old, but maybe that will help someone someday!

Answer (score -1):

I user polymorphic associations a lot!

I would first watch this [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association) and then the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) suggested by [nicholaides](https://stackoverflow.com/users/48424/nicholaides).

It perfectly explains how to create both sides of the association.