# Rails 3 ActiveRecord has_many polymorphic - Why isn't the id of the first object being saved for insertion into the join table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many, polymorphism

Wise people,

Please help me troubleshoot my has_many polymorphic object creation problem.

I have a polymorphic has_many relationship between two objects with a join table in the middle.  Acronyms (and other objects) on one side, Categories on the other.  In between them, I have a join object between the two objects.

I cannot successfully create an acronym with a category.  I can, however, create an acronym without a category, then add the category to the existing acronym.

My model objects look like the following code:

```
class Acronym < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :category_belongings, :as => :categorizable, :dependent => :delete_all
  has_many :categories, :through => :category_belongings
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :category_belongings, :dependent => :delete_all
  has_many :acronyms, :through => :category_belongings, :source => :categorizable, :source_type => 'Acronym'
end

class CategoryBelonging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :categorizable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :category
end
```

For reference, I removed some extra fields and irrelevant rules.  I also refactored my code to look just like the example here:
[Setting up a polymorphic has_many :through relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886738/setting-up-a-polymorphic-has-many-through-relationship/6011770#6011770)

Through my Rails application/rails console, I am able to:

- Successfully create an acronym without any categories
- Successfully create a category
- Successfully add an existing category to an existing acronym through updating the acronym

I cannot, however, create a new acronym with an existing category.  I can see in the logs Rails tries to do the following:

1. Gathers the parameters from the post.  These parameters include the columns on the Acronym table as well as the category IDs
2. Checks to see if the Category exists.  It does.
3. Checks to see if the Acronym exists.  It does not.
4. Inserts a new Acronym into the database with all the column parameters
5. Attempts to insert a new entry in the join table.  This is where the error is.  The SQL for this insertion contains a Nil value for the Acronym ID.
6. Rolls my changes back.

   ```
   Processing by Admin::AcronymsController#create as HTML
     Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"/uquz5FvtMh0QWP5NoWwTO9FMMEC9rsMTrTj4WUNxxE=", "acronym"=>{"name"=>"A Test Acronym", "definition"=>"A Test Definition", "explanation"=>"", "category_ids"=>["1", ""], "state"=>"unapproved"}, "commit"=>"Create Acronym"}
     Category Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
      (0.3ms)  BEGIN
     Category Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "categories" WHERE ("categories"."name" = 'Internet' AND "categories"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1
     Acronym Exists (26.0ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "acronyms" WHERE "acronyms"."name" = 'A Test Acronym' LIMIT 1
     SQL (18.1ms)  INSERT INTO "acronyms" ("definition", "explanation", "improvement_reason", "likes_count", "name", "state", "submitter_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["definition", "A Test Definition"], ["explanation", ""], ["improvement_reason", nil], ["likes_count", 0], ["name", "A Test Acronym"], ["state", "unapproved"], ["submitter_id", nil]]
     SQL (55.8ms)  INSERT INTO "category_belongings" ("categorizable_id", "categorizable_type", "category_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["categorizable_id", nil], ["categorizable_type", "Acronym"], ["category_id", 1], ["created_at", Thu, 28 Feb 2013 23:03:48 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Thu, 28 Feb 2013 23:03:48 UTC +00:00]]
   PG::Error: ERROR:  null value in column "categorizable_id" violates not-null constraint
   : INSERT INTO "category_belongings" ("categorizable_id", "categorizable_type", "category_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"
      (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
   ```

I would assume on the Acronym insert, an acronym_id would be created, but I don't see any output indicating what the value of that acronym_id is.  To me, the error is clearly that the acronym_id is Nil when I try to insert the new row into category_belongings.  Do I need to somehow point acronym_id to categorizable_id?  If that's the case, how would I do this?

I'm new to rails, and I am trying to maintain and improve an existing system.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: You have a lot going on here. It looks like what you want is just `has_many: :through` so you can join your Acronym and Category models. Is there a particular reason you set up the polymorphic association?

Comment: I used a polymorphic association because Acronyms are not the only entities which use Categories.  I have some other classes with a similar association.  The other classes are experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Did you make sure to have `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in your models? Im not seeing that in your pasted code and having that is key so rails knows it can create the models within the same form.  If you have all that, then pasting a copy of your form might also be helpful

Comment: I tried this exactly as mentioned in your post and received an error:  "No association found for name `acronyms'. Has it been defined yet?" I reading the documentation you sent me to read.  One thing to clarify - I do not need to create a category at the same time as an acronym.  The categories are pre-defined - I only want to create an acronym pointing to an existing category.  The system trips because it's setting a row in the join table with a null acronym id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems my code was fine - I got bit by a Rails bug.  I solved the problem by moving my rails version to 3.2.8 with the security patch enabled according to these instructions.  After that, everything worked fine with no code changes necessary.

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/8269#issuecomment-10518099

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you are looking to do, you need to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.  This will allow you to create a category when you create an acronym. Here is how you should set it up.

```
class Acronym < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories, :through => :category_belongings
  has_many :category_belongings, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :acronyms

  attr_accessible :acronyms_attributes      
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :acronyms, :through => :category_belongings
  has_many :category_belongings, :dependent => :destroy     
end

class CategoryBelonging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :acronym
  belongs_to :category
end
```

This setup will allow you to nest your forms and create a category when you create an acronym.  To read more about all the options `accepts_nested_attributes_for` has checkout the [Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html). This [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised) also has some good information on nested forms.