# rails_admin giving me reflection error when installing initializer

Tags: rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

Here's what it shows when I run the installer. The output is strange with some complaint about foreign key and reflection. source_reflection is nil? Any idea as to a fix?

Also, S.O. is really annoying by not letting me post this question unless I add a bunch of additional dribble to fill out this form. Come on S.O!!!

```
 -  Hello, RailsAdmin installer will help you set things up!
       -  I need to work with Devise, let's look at a few things first:
       -  Checking for a current installation of devise...
       -  Found it!
       -  Looks like you've already installed it, good!
       ?  Where do you want to mount rails_admin? Press <enter> for [admin] > 
    gsub  config/routes.rb
   route  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', :as => 'rails_admin'
       -  And you already set it up, good! We just need to know about your user model name...
       -  We found 'user' (should be one of 'user', 'admin', etc.)
       ?  Correct Devise model name if needed. Press <enter> for [user] > admin
       -  Now setting up devise with user model name 'admin':
generate  devise
  invoke  active_record
  create    db/migrate/20131114155103_add_devise_to_admins.rb
  insert    app/models/admin.rb
   route  devise_for :admins
       -  Now you'll need an initializer...
  create  config/initializers/rails_admin.rb
/Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:401:in `rescue in foreign_key': ActiveRecord::Reflection::ThroughReflection#foreign_key delegated to source_reflection.foreign_key, but source_reflection is nil: #<ActiveRecord::Reflection::ThroughReflection:0x007f87de0c5bd0 @macro=:has_many, @name=:transactions, @scope=nil, @options={:through=>:locatables}, @active_record=Address(id: integer, street: string, city: string, state: string, zip: string, country: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, latitude: float, longitude: float), @plural_name="transactions", @collection=true, @source_reflection_names=[:transaction, :transactions], @through_reflection=#<ActiveRecord::Reflection::AssociationReflection:0x007f87dafbb670 @macro=:has_many, @name=:locatables, @scope=nil, @options={}, @active_record=Address(id: integer, street: string, city: string, state: string, zip: string, country: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, latitude: float, longitude: float), @plural_name="locatables", @collection=true, @foreign_key="address_id", @class_name="Locatable", @klass=Locatable(id: integer, owner_id: integer, owner_type: string, address_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, pickup: boolean, kind: string)>, @source_reflection=nil> (RuntimeError)
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:397:in `foreign_key'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/rails_admin-0.5.0/lib/rails_admin/adapters/active_record.rb:306:in `association_foreign_key_lookup'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/rails_admin-0.5.0/lib/rails_admin/adapters/active_record.rb:72:in `block in associations'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/rails_admin-0.5.0/lib/rails_admin/adapters/active_record.rb:65:in `map'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/rails_admin-0.5.0/lib/rails_admin/adapters/active_record.rb:65:in `associations'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/rails_admin-0.5.0/lib/rails_admin/config/fields/factories/association.rb:6:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/rails_admin-0.5.0/lib/rails_admin/config/fields.rb:54:in `call'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/rails_admin-0.5.0/lib/rails_admin/config/fields.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in factory'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/rails_admin-0.5.0/lib/rails_admin/config/fields.rb:54:in `each'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/rails_admin-0.5.0/lib/rails_admin/config/fields.rb:54:in `find'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/rails_admin-0.5.0/lib/rails_admin/config/fields.rb:54:in `block in factory'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/rails_admin-0.5.0/lib/rails_admin/config/fields.rb:50:in `each'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/rails_admin-0.5.0/lib/rails_admin/config/fields.rb:50:in `factory'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/rails_admin-0.5.0/lib/rails_admin/config/has_fields.rb:130:in `_fields'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/rails_admin-0.5.0/lib/rails_admin/config/has_fields.rb:128:in `_fields'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/rails_admin-0.5.0/lib/rails_admin/config/has_fields.rb:108:in `all_fields'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/rails_admin-0.5.0/lib/rails_admin/config/has_fields.rb:83:in `fields'
    from (erb):64:in `block in template'
    from (erb):53:in `map'
    from (erb):53:in `template'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/erb.rb:849:in `eval'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/erb.rb:849:in `result'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/actions/file_manipulation.rb:117:in `block in template'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:54:in `call'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:54:in `render'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:63:in `block (2 levels) in invoke!'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:63:in `open'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:63:in `block in invoke!'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:117:in `call'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:117:in `invoke_with_conflict_check'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:61:in `invoke!'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/actions.rb:95:in `action'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:26:in `create_file'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/actions/file_manipulation.rb:116:in `template'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/rails_admin-0.5.0/lib/generators/rails_admin/install_generator.rb:75:in `install'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_command'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `block in invoke_all'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `each'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `map'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_all'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/group.rb:233:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/base.rb:439:in `start'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/generators.rb:156:in `invoke'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/generate.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from /Users/JCC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@testing/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

This error took me a while to suss out. Another SO answer as well as some outside assitance gave me the clues as to what's giving the errors.  That SO is here [reflection error with polymorphic association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677703/source-reflection-errors-with-has-many-through)

The other SO which helped me was to understand how you need to make the associations clearer for rails, or in this case, rails admin, as it needs to know all of the relationships in order to present it to the admin. [:source options in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632408/need-help-to-understand-source-option-of-has-one-has-many-through-of-rails)

The problem was that I had a polymorphic association that wasn't very clear to rails of the source. Once I removed the source of rails admin's confusion I was able to proceed with no errors.

Two items of note:

1. If you have already created an admin class with devise, you'll have to edit or delete the migration file automatically generated by rails admin.  It's called AddDeviseToAdmins.  Make sure to edit it so it doesn't duplicate the fields you already have in your current admin table. In my case I deleted the file entirely as my default devise generated admin table already contained everything there.
2. That first S.O. has the second option as :source-type => "something", it's mistyped.  It should be :source_type => "something".  Use an underscore and not a dash.