# Rails association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, polymorphic-associations

I am having trouble with polymorphic associations, and at this point I don't know if I should be using this association for what I'm trying to accomplish:

I have three models:  `Post`, `Project`, and `Photo`

I want to be able to associate a `Photo` record with both a `Post` and a `Project` record.  If I have a `Photo` associated with a `Project`, and then I then try to associate it with a `Post`, it disappears from that `Poject`, but successfully attached to that `Post`.

Should I just be doing this:

```
Post
has_one :photo

Project 
has_one :photo

Photo
belongs_to :post
belongs_to :project
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing, is not a regular polymorphic association (which allows a dynamic associated parent, but only one).
You seem to need either a 1 to many polymorphic association, or simply have both `project_id` and `post_id` on the photo model.

I believe that the latter option is the better one, unless you absolutely know you are going to need to associate a photo with **more** models.

In case you still want to go with the many_polymorphic approach: here is a good example 
[Setting up a polymorphic has_many :through relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886738/setting-up-a-polymorphic-has-many-through-relationship)

Comment: Thanks!  I went with the simple solution (ids on the photo model).

Answer (score 1):

If you want associate photo with post and project at the same time, you are right to declare relations like this :

```
Post
  has_one :photo

Project 
  has_one :photo

Photo
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :project
```

just what you need to add is `:dependent => :nullify` which updates the associated records foreign key value to NULL for this removed object(project or post) so your `has_one :photo` become :

```
 Post
  has_one :photo, :dependent => :nullify

 Project 
  has_one :photo, :dependent => :nullify
```

**remember** that your **photos table** need **post_id** and **project_id** attributes which references both your project and post.

Just for completeness if you want to destroying photo when you your post/project is destroyed use :dependent => :destroy, if you don't add anything the foreign key still referenced which is not good idea at all.

For more details about has_one association check documentation : http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one

Hope that help you

Comment: Helps a lot!  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
class Post
  has_one :photo, as: :photoable
end

class Project
  has_one :photo, as: :photoable
end

class Photo
  belongs_to :photoable, polymorphic: true
end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html (check out section 2.9 on polymorphic associations)

Comment: Thanks Artin.  This is what I have. The problem is that when I associate a photo with both a post and a project, it gets removed from whatever it was associated with first.  So if a photo is associated with a project, and then I want to associate it with a post as well, it gets removed from the project.

Comment: Looks like polymorphic is the wrong association to use.  The photo record has photoable_type: "Post" on it, so it can't be associated with both a Post and a Photo

Comment: I see your issue now. Just out of curiosity, if you did something like: photo = Photo.last (assuming this photo belongs to a project through a polymorphic relationship - photoable_type: "Project"). And you loaded up a Post, post = Post.last. If you did new_photo = post.new_photo(url: photo.url) (I don't know what attributes a photo has so i'm just making up url). It would simply reassign the photo we pulled from the database to the post?