# Rails 4: combining has_many :through association with polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, has-many-through, polymorphic-associations

In my Rails 4 app, I have the following models:

```
User
has_many :administrations
has_many :calendars, through: :administrations
has_many :comments
has_many :calendar_comments, through: :calendars, :source => :comments

Calendar
has_many :administrations
has_many :users, through: :administrations
has_many :posts
has_many :comments, through: posts
has_many :ads

Administration
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :calendar

Post
belongs_to :calendar
has_many :comments, as: :commentable

Ad
belongs_to :calendar
has_many :comments, as: :commentable

Comment
belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
belongs_to :user
```

I need to access the `comments` that `belong_to` an `ad` from the `calendar` the `ad` `belongs_to`.

This is what I am trying to do in my `Calendars#Index` action:

```
@posts_comments = @user.calendar_comments.where(commentable_type: "Post").order("created_at DESC").limit(5)
@ads_comments = @user.calendar_comments.where(commentable_type: "Ad").order("created_at DESC").limit(5)
```

My first guess was to add `has_many :comments, through: ads` in the Calendar model:

```
Calendar
has_many :administrations
has_many :users, through: :administrations
has_many :posts
has_many :comments, through: posts
has_many : ads
has_many :comments, through: ads
```

But that cancels the effect of `has_many :comments, through: posts` and then I can no longer access the `comments` that `belong_to` an `post` from the `calendar` the `post` `belongs_to`.

Is there a way to make **BOTH** `has_many :comments, through: posts` **AND** `has_many :comments, through: ads` work?

—————

**UPDATE**: according to [this article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2220311&seqNum=6) and [that Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886738/setting-up-a-polymorphic-has-many-through-relationship), the answer may lay in the use of `source:` and `source_type:`.

Not sure how to use those however.

—————

**UPDATE 2**: would the following code make any sense?

```
class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :administrations
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :commented_posts, through: :comments, source: :commentable, source_type: 'Post'
  has_many :ads, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :commented_ads, through: :comments, source: :commentable, source_type: 'Ad'
```

—————

**UPDATE 3**: when I try the above code, I get the following error message:

```
Could not find the source association(s) :comments in model Calendar. Try 'has_many :calendar_comments, :through => :calendars, :source => <name>'. Is it one of administrations, users, posts, commented_posts, ads, commented_ads, invites, or pokes?
```

I tried the following:

```
class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :administrations
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :calendar_comments, :through => :calendars, :source => :post
  has_many :ads, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :calendar_comments, :through => :calendars, :source => :ad
```

—————

**UPDATE 4**: a new failed attempt with the following code:

```
class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :administrations
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :calendar_comments, :through => :commentable, :source => :post
  has_many :ads, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :calendar_comments, :through => :commentable, :source => :ad
```

Still not working, same error message as above.

—————

**UPDATE 5**: based on **MrYoshiji**'s answer, I now have

```
class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :administrations
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :posts_comments, through: :posts, source_type: 'Post'
  has_many :ads, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :ads_comments, through: :ads, source_type: 'Ad'
```

Now, `has_many :calendar_comments, through: :calendars, :source => :comments` in the `User` model is no longer working.

I tried:

```
has_many :comments
has_many :calendar_post_comments, through: :calendars, :source => :post_comments
has_many :calendar_ad_comments, through: :calendars, :source => :ad_comments
```

Still not working.

—————

**UPDATE 6**: I am still stuck with this issue, since I cannot figure out a way to get the following code working:

```
@posts_comments = @user.calendar_comments.where(commentable_type: "Post").order("created_at DESC").limit(5)
@ads_comments = @user.calendar_comments.where(commentable_type: "Ad").order("created_at DESC").limit(5)
```

I tried many different things, and the best I could come up with so far was:

```
class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :administrations
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :post_comments, through: :posts, source_type: 'Post'
  has_many :ads, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :ad_comments, through: :ads, source_type: 'Ad'
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :calendars, through: :administrations
  has_many :comments
  has_many :calendar_post_comments, through: :calendars, :source => :post_comments
  has_many :calendar_ad_comments, through: :calendars, :source => :ad_comments
end
```

Then, I update my Calendars controller as follows:

```
def index
    @user = current_user
    @calendars = @user.calendars.all
    @posts_comments = @user.calendar_post_comments
                              .order("created_at DESC")
                              .limit(5)
    @ads_comments = @user.calendar_ad.comments
                              .order("created_at DESC")
                              .limit(5)
end
```

But this returns the following error:

```
NoMethodError at /calendars
undefined method `chain' for nil:NilClass
@posts_comments = @user.calendar_post_comments.order("created_at DESC").limit(5)
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: You cannot use the same relation name for the different relations (you should rename `calendar_comments` to `post_comments` and `ad_comments`). Also, you can remove all the unrelevant parts of your code (`has_many :invites` is not useful here)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try the following:

```
class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  # [ ... ]
  has_many :posts
  has_many :posts_comments, through: posts, source_type: 'Post'
  has_many :ads
  has_many :ads_comments, through: ads, source_type: 'Ad'
```

Considering that `Ad` and `Post` models both have the following:

```
has_many :comments, as: :commentable
```

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. And what does that imply for the `User` model? I currently have `has_many :comments
  has_many :calendar_comments, through: :calendars, :source => :comments` but this is no longer working.

Comment: try replacing `:source => :comments` with `source_type: 'Comment'`

Comment: Done. Now, I get: `NoMethodError at /calendars undefined method 'post_comments' for #<User:0x007fcb21741870>`. I guess this is because we do not declare `post_comments` and `ad_comments` in the `User` model, right?

Comment: You can declare these two or you can simply do the logic yourself instead of declaring the `has_many :posts_comments` in the User model