# Polymorphics in Rails ' uninitialized constant' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model, polymorphic-associations

I wanted to make polymorphic association in my project so I followe rails guide to do it but I got: `NameError: uninitialized constant DashboardAssignment::Assignable`
error.

**Models:**

DashboardAssignment:

```
class DashboardAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dashboard
  belongs_to :assignable, polymorphic: true

  validates :dashboard, presence: true
  validates :assignable, presence: true, uniqueness: { :scope => :dashboard }
end
```

User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dashboard_assignments, as: :assignable
  has_many :dashboards, through: :dashboard_assignments
end
```

Group:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :dashboard_assignment, as: :assignable
  has_many :laboratories_assignments, as: :lab_assignable
end
```

Dashboard:

```
class Dashboard < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :building
  has_many :dashboard_assignments
  has_many :users, through: :dashboard_assignments, as: :assignable
end
```

In DashboardAssignment **Migration** file I have:

```
t.references :assignable, null: false, polymorphic: true, index: true
```

When I try to create new DashboardAssignment by `DashboardAssignment.create(assignable: u)` where `u = User.find(1)`
it gives me error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant DashboardAssignment::Assignable
    from P:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:158:in `compute_type' ...
```

Am I doing something wrong?

My rails version is **4.2.6**

Comment: What the error is telling you is that there is no attribute or association called assignable on the DashboardAssignment class.  Can you please post your Dashboard model please?

Comment: ok. added Dashboard model

Comment: I am quite sure, your problem exists because of:

has_many :users, through: :dashboard_assignments, as: :assignable

Comment: I think this one can help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886738/setting-up-a-polymorphic-has-many-through-relationship

Comment: tried with source: instead of as: and still the same

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `source` instead of `as` in a `through` association

```
class Dashboard < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :building
  has_many :dashboard_assignments
  has_many :users, through: :dashboard_assignments, source: :assignable
end
```

I would caution though that this might give you `assignables` that are of class `Group`. The best way to go around this issue is by adding a condition to a `has_many` for `dashboard_assignments` that let's you filter only for `dashboard_assignments` that have `assignable_type = 'User'`:

```
class Dashboard < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :building
  has_many :user_dashboard_assignments, -> { where(assignable_type: 'User') }, class_name: 'DashboardAssignment'
  has_many :users, through: :user_dashboard_assignments, source: :assignable
end
```

Comment: I tried changing these lines but same error still occurs. My project is open source there: https://github.com/GRM-dev/IMP/tree/Polimorphic on polimorphic branch

Comment: Ahhh  that was probably my mistake :)
In DashboardAssignment I had a line  `validates :assignable, presence: true, uniqueness: { :scope => :dashboard }` 
When I removed it and changed `as:` to `source:` everything seems working fine. Also added `source_type: "User"` to that line.