# Rails has_many association through a belongs_to polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my database there are 4 models

```
class MasterPayment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :payments
end

class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :master_payment
  belongs_to :payable, polymorphic: :true
end

class TreatmentPlan < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :payments, as: :payable
end

class ArbitraryBillableItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :payments, as: :payable
end
```

What i would like to do is set up an association in MasterPayment that will associate payables to master payments.

Currently, the closest i could find was setting up the master payment model as follows

```
class MasterPayment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :payments
  has_many :treatment_plans, through: :payments, source: :payable, source_type: "TreatmentPlan"
  has_many :arbitrary_billable_items, through: :payments, source: :payable, source_type: "ArbitraryBillableItem"

  def payables
    self.treatment_plans + self.arbitrary_billable_items
  end
end
```

The only problem i have with this is that it doesn't feel like the "correct" way to do it.

The only reason i can see for rails not having a solution to this is because you would presumably have to union the tables to return it in one sql statement.

Is there an alternative way to accomplish this that will make more use of the active record associations?

Comment: The problem, as you've discovered, is that TreatmentPlan and  ArbitraryBillableItem are two separate tables. Have you considered combining them into a single table and using single-table inheritance to subclass both from the same parent?  Another, less conventional approach would be to use a database view to generate a result set from the two tables. You can create an ActiveRecord model that uses a view as its table, and therefore you'll have a result set that is an ActiveRecord relation rather than an array (which is what you'll get with the plus operator)

Comment: so your are following http://stackoverflow.com/a/5887290/1657377 (kind of), I would rather suggest to take the time to reconsider your abstraction(s) if it feels odd, basically you are encapsulating things in payments just to provide them to master_payments anyhow so why the abstraction in the first place?

Comment: @JPlato I had not previously looked into views, it does seem to be most of what I would be looking for seeing as my current issue is how it doesn't "feel correct" to have it done through a method given the rails active record conventions.. Unfortunately combining them will also probably not be an option at this point in time, given the complexity of the change on the application side.

Comment: @jethroo I have certainly spent time considering if the master payment table should exist or not. And although it does not necessarily need to be there it was originally added to the database as a tool to collect payments made together for line item breakdowns. Unfortunately as i said in my last comment the application is a couple of years past an easy change to these tables' setup

Answer (score 0):

This seems too simple but would it work?

```
def payables
  self.payments.joins(:treatment_plans, :arbitrary_billable_items).distinct
end
```

Comment: with the polymorphic relationship pointing to "payable" this setup won't quite work.

This also would suffer from the drawback I was trying to get around that it is not controlled via the rails active record association helpers